# How to close previous jframe on the new open jframe

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have a problem in disposing the two JFrames in one click of a button. I have a 2 JFrames(SUC_Forms and add_suc) when the button "ADD RECORDS" in SUC_Forms was click another new JFrame will show which is the add_suc jframe that contains textboxes for registration/filing. When i press ok to validate and insert all the data in the database, a JDialogbox will pop-up for a confirmation. Once I hit "Ok" both JFrames will dispose and then SUC_Forms-JFrame will show again containing the updated data. I have a trouble on how the current JFrames has an access to the previous and active JFrame. Can you pls help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance..

Heres my print screen.

[image]

SUC_Forms Code:

```
    add_suc add = new add_suc();
    add.show();
```

add_suc Code:

private void btn_okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    int verify = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane,"Are you sure you want to add this record?","", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if(verify == 0)
    {

       String moa_id = txt_id.getText();
       Object region = cmb_region.getSelectedItem();
       String holder = txt_holder.getText();
       String brgy = txt_brgy.getText();
       String municipality = txt_municipality.getText();
       String province = txt_province.getText();
       String president = txt_president.getText();
       Object month = cmb_month.getSelectedItem();
       Object day = cmb_day.getSelectedItem();
       String year = txt_year.getText();
       String area = txt_area.getText();
       String allotment = txt_allotment.getText();
       String activities = txt_activities.getText();
       String status = txt_status.getText();
       String fill = "";

       if(moa_id.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill Moa ID!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }

       if(region.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please select region!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
       else if(holder.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill holder!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
       else if(brgy.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill barangay!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
       else if(municipality.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill municipality!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
       else if(province.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill province!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
        else if(president.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill president/representative!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
        else if(month.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please set the month of Date Approved field!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }

       else if(day.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please set the date of Date Approved field!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
       else if(year.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please set the year of Date Approved field!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
       else if(area.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill area!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
       else if(allotment.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill allotment!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
       else if(activities.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill activities/roles!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }
       else if(status.equals(fill))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill status!", "Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,null);
       }

       else{

        try{

        st = con.createStatement();

        String query =  "insert into moa_suc values('"+moa_id+"','"+region+"','"+holder+"','"+brgy+"','"+municipality+"','"+province+"','"+president+"','"+month+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+area+"','"+allotment+"','"+activities+"','"+status+"')";

        st.executeUpdate(query);

        txt_id.setText("");
        cmb_region.setSelectedItem(0);
        txt_holder.setText("");
        txt_brgy.setText("");
        txt_municipality.setText("");
        txt_province.setText("");
        txt_president.setText("");
        cmb_month.setSelectedItem(0);
        cmb_day.setSelectedItem(0);
        txt_year.setText("");
        txt_area.setText("");
        txt_allotment.setText("");
        txt_activities.setText("");
        txt_status.setText("");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Successfully added to the record!", "Message",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null);
        this.dispose();

    }
    catch(SQLException err){

        System.out.println(err.toString());   
    }

     }

    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Sorry! No data added in the record!", "Message",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of closing the frame and reopening it. Wouldn't it make more sense to reload the GUI?

Comment: I dont think so. But in my case, I want to reload the JFrame to be able to refresh its content most especially my jTable. I think reloading JFrame again is the easy way to refresh my data. I am new in java netbeans so I have a little knowledge on how to used different methods. Im hoping that by the used of forums and asking questions will help to improved my knowledge regarding this. Anyway, thanks for showing interest to my questions/problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the JFrame you want to add the new record to is still open you could use a method in SUC_Forms where you pass the new record as a parameter. To be able to do that you would have to get a reference to SUC_Forms in add_suc. For example you can pass this reference to the constructor of add_suc when you are opening this Frame. Then you can call the method to add the record using the reference to SUC_Forms.

Your constructor would look something like this:

```
add_suc(SUC_Forms parent)
{}
```

And in SUC_Forms you create a method like:

```
public void addRecord(-here you pass the required parameters-)
{}
```

Your method call in add_suc would then be:

```
parent.addRecord(-parameters-);
```

I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I try to used your recommendations.. I hope it will work. Thanks again :)

Comment: No Problem. Feel free to report back after you tried :)

Comment: Nothing happens. Or maybe im not totally understand your answers to my questions hahaha..

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "nothing" ? Do you get error messages ? Have you debuged and the addRecord() method gets called  ?

Comment: Whats the purposed of addRecord();? I already create a method for inserting records into my database and it works fine. All I want is when a "ok button" in the add_suc form is pressed, the add_suc and SUC_Forms JFrame will close together. And show the SUC_Forms again..